# Remove empty lines from 7zip output stream in Powershell

Tags: powershell, stream, find, 7zip

I'm extracting .tgz archives with Powershell and 7zip. 7zip has a forced verbose mode and pollutes my screen. I just want to **display the error messages**. I already removed the standard messages with FIND:

Code:

```
  Write-Host "Extracting "$strArgument

  # extract tgz to tar
  & "$7z" x "-y" $strArgument | FIND /V "ing  " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "Processing " | FIND /V "Everything is Ok" | FIND /V "Folders: " | FIND /V "Files: " | FIND /V "Size: " | FIND /V "Compressed: " | FIND /V "Processing archive: "

  # path to .tar
  $strArgument = $strArgument.Replace(".tgz", ".tar")
  $strArgument = $strArgument.Replace("i\data\", "")

  # extract tar to file
  #Write-Host $strArgument
  & "$7z" x "-y" $strArgument | FIND /V "ing  " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "Processing " | FIND /V "Everything is Ok" | FIND /V "Folders: " | FIND /V "Files: " | FIND /V "Size: " | FIND /V "Compressed: " | FIND /V "Processing archive: "
```

This gives me an output with lots of empty lines:

```
Extracting  Q:\mles\etl-i_test\i\data\divider-bin.tgz










Extracting  Q:\mles\etl-i_test\i\data\divider-conf.tgz
...
```

However I just want:

```
Extracting  Q:\mles\etl-i_test\i\data\divider-bin.tgz
Extracting  Q:\mles\etl-i_test\i\data\divider-conf.tgz
```

How can i remove the blank lines from my stream? Is there a mighty FIND switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` does not have a switch like that, but you can use `findstr` with a regular expression instead:

```
... | findstr /r /v "^$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I know is to run the result through -match and filter out anything that doesn't contain non-whitespace:

```
Write-Host "Extracting "$strArgument

  # extract tgz to tar
  & "$7z" x "-y" $strArgument | FIND /V "ing  " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "Processing " | FIND /V "Everything is Ok" | FIND /V "Folders: " | FIND /V "Files: " | FIND /V "Size: " | FIND /V "Compressed: " | FIND /V "Processing archive: "

  # path to .tar
  $strArgument = $strArgument.Replace(".tgz", ".tar")
  $strArgument = $strArgument.Replace("i\data\", "")

  # extract tar to file
  #Write-Host $strArgument
  (& "$7z" x "-y" $strArgument | FIND /V "ing  " | FIND /V "Igor Pavlov" | FIND /V "Processing " |   ND /V "Everything is Ok" | FIND /V "Folders: " | FIND /V "Files: " | FIND /V "Size: " | FIND /V "Compressed: " | FIND /V "Processing archive: ") -match '\S'
```

Comment: is it possible to put all of the FINDs in a single regex for -match too?

Comment: Yes, and no. You can put them all in a single regex using alternation, but the way you're doing it you'd want to use -notmatch against that regex. It would probably be much easier to write the regex to match the lines you want to keep.  eg -match '^Extracting'.  I'd have offered exactly that as a better solution but the bit about only wanting to keep errors made me think there might be more to it that would need to be included.